# Custom mime type for input element

Tags: html, browser

According to the spec at https://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/input/file

The "accept" attribute is a series of MIME types.

In this case (i.e. the file is not coming from a server), is it possible to set a custom MIME type for a certain file extension or binary file peeking (e.g. some procedure to read the header)?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to do here. A couple of possibly interpretations: "Can I limit the files that a file input will accept based on something other than a MIME type the browser knows about?" and "Can I specify what Content-Type the browser will label a file when when I submit a form with a file input in it?"

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can set custom MIME types.

[The Living Standard specification states](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/input.html#attr-input-accept) "The accept attribute may be specified to provide user agents with a hint of what file types will be accepted."

To use this, use the following `<input type="file" name="example" accept=
"your-custom-extension-1, your-custom-extension-2, your-custom-extension-3">`

In addition, read the following statement about the accept [attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input): "If the value of the type attribute is file, then this attribute will indicate the types of files that the server accepts, otherwise it will be ignored".